# MessageBox showing unwanted result

Tags: c#, messagebox

I'm new at this world of developing a software. So this may sound silly.

I'm working on developing a simple Login System at college, and I want to speed things up a little bit, my professor can be a tad, disorganized and it jeopardize the little time we have to learn a million things about programming.

I could get the program running and only opening the Main Form if the username and password are valid.

Before I researched and made a register button that will write data in my database, the message box was working properly.

But now, I cannot seem to make the message box show up saying if it is either, a successful login or if it is not.

My code is as following for the Login button:

```
private void VLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        string ConnectionString = "User ID=*****;Password=*******;" +
                "Database=C:\\Users\\marqu_000\\Documents\\WindowsFormsApplication13\\Sistema.GDB;" +
                "DataSource=localhost";
        FbConnection addDetailsConnection = new FbConnection(ConnectionString);
        addDetailsConnection.Open();
        string SQLCommandText = "select * from LOGIN where USERNAME=@username and PASSWORD=@password";
        FbCommand addDetailsCommand = new FbCommand(SQLCommandText, addDetailsConnection);
        addDetailsCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", FbDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = userName.Text;
        addDetailsCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", FbDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = userPassword.Text;
        FbDataReader reader = addDetailsCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {   
            this.Visible = false;
            MainWin MWin = new MainWin();
            MWin.ShowDialog();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
        MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
    }
}
```

And this is my code for the register button:

```
private void registerUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        string ConnectionString = "User ID=****;Password=****;" +
                                     "Database=C:\\Users\\marqu_000\\Documents\\WindowsFormsApplication13\\Sistema.GDB;" +
                                      "DataSource=localhost";
        FbConnection addDetailsConnection = new FbConnection(ConnectionString);
        addDetailsConnection.Open();
        FbCommand SQLCommandTextInsert = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO LOGIN(USERNAME, PASSWORD, LEVEL) VALUES (@username,@password,@level)", addDetailsConnection);
        SQLCommandTextInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", registerUsername.Text);
        SQLCommandTextInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", registerPassword.Text);
        SQLCommandTextInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("level", registerLevel.Text);
        SQLCommandTextInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Registration completed!");
    }
    catch (FbException fbex)
    {
        //throw fbex;
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid information, please verify!");
        MessageBox.Show(fbex.Message);
    }
}
```

If there is any good-for-nothing lines in there, and easiest ways to make those things, I would like to know.
I thank you all in advance for the help.
Marco.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I have edited your question to remove the username and password from the connection string.  Please refrain from including items like that in future questions.

Comment: Which message box doesn't show up? is it the one after the `ShowDialog` blocking call and `Application.Exit`? using exceptions as a way to control program flow isn't a great way of doing things.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of your `VLogin_Click` method, then hit F5.  You can step through the code and see what exactly is going on.

Comment: You call `Application.Exit();` in your loop with the reader, so if there is a match returned from the database you'll exit the program.  Is this your intent?

Comment: @Tim - If that is indeed the "erroneous" messagebox as I think then I think it just needs to be before the `ShowDialog`, I guess `MainWin` is just the window that he wants to open after a successful login and when that closes, then it is ok to close the program

Comment: I did a few changes, move the "Login successful" message box to right after 'this.Visible = false' and commented the 'Application.Exit()' inside the while. But still, if I write a wrong username and password, the invalid info message doesn't show.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Tim and thanks also Matthew, I'll be more careful with username and passwords, I didn't think it was a problem since this is the default of Firebird.

Comment: @MarcoOliveira - You're welcome.  Please tell me you are *not* planning on using Firebird's default username and password in your application....

Comment: hahah no I'm not, since this is only to college, I didn't make my own username and password. Once I engage in a real project, I shall use a different database even!

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog` is a blocking call, that means no code will run until that call completes. Which in this case is when your MWin closes. You'll need to display the success message before calling ShowDialog or call it from MWin.

Your Login failed message will only show when an exception occurs. I think if i read your code correctly if the reader returns no results (failed login) then you'll display "Login Succesful" and then doing nothing else.

You can use an `if` to determine if the database returned results and login failed is your `else` condition.

Comment: I did what you said and moved the 'MessageBox' to before the 'ShowDialog'. Would you care to show an example of the if?

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it!
I searched how to validate with a IF and could do it. This is how my code is now:

```
try
        {
            string ConnectionString = "User ID=*****;Password=*******;" +
                "Database=C:\\Users\\marqu_000\\Documents\\WindowsFormsApplication13\\Sistema.GDB;" +
                "DataSource=localhost";
            FbConnection addDetailsConnection = new FbConnection(ConnectionString);
            addDetailsConnection.Open();
            string SQLCommandText = "select * from LOGIN where USERNAME=@username and PASSWORD=@password";
            FbCommand addDetailsCommand = new FbCommand(SQLCommandText, addDetailsConnection);
            addDetailsCommand.Parameters.Add("@username", FbDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = userName.Text;
            addDetailsCommand.Parameters.Add("@password", FbDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = userPassword.Text;
            FbDataReader reader = addDetailsCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                this.Visible = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");
                MainWin MWin = new MainWin();
                MWin.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!");
            }
```